# How to get text using xpath from specific line within iframe tag - Robot Framework

Tags: html, xpath, iframe, robotframework

How can I get the text within the iframe tag?
I need the code 123456 from the fifth line without the string ‘Your code is: ’

```
<div class="x_content">
                <iframe id="msg_body">
                        <html>
                            <head><head>
                            <body marginheight="0">
                        <br>
                        "You are using browser"
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        "Browser name"
                        <br>
                        "OS name"
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        "Hello World"
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        "Your code is: 123456"
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        "Bye Bye"
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                                </body>
                        <html>
                   " EMAIL BODY "
                </iframe>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a library as [rpaframework](https://rpaframework.org/), that will most likely to help you what you are trying to achieve.

[Here](https://rpaframework.org/libdoc/RPA_Browser_Selenium.html#Select%20Frame) you'll find how to select an iframe and after selecting that iframe you can fetch the text using [Get Text](https://rpaframework.org/libdoc/RPA_Browser_Selenium.html#Get%20Text).

```
${text}    Get Text    <xpath_for_that_line>
```

After getting the text in ${text} variable, use string library to split the string from ':'

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String
*** Tasks ***
task 1
    ${text}    Get Text    <xpath_for_that_line>
    ${c}    Split String    ${text}    :
    Log    ${c}[1]
```

Complete Code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library    String
*** Tasks ***
task 1
    Open Available Browser    https://your_url_here
    Select Frame    //iframe[@id='msg_body']
    ${text}    Get Text    <xpath_for_that_line>
    ${c}    Split String    ${text}    :
    Log    ${c}[1]
```

> **Note:** Do not forget to install rpaframework library

```
pip install rpaframework
```

If you posted the website link containing this iframe also, then code could be improved more.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm getting the following error for ${text} Get Text //html/body/text()[5] ****** InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//html/body/text()[5]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: You should provide the correct xpath containing that line, as I don't have web-page so I have given just the example there.

Comment: I have removed that xpath from the answer as it will not work for everyone.

Comment: That’s the point of my question, since I fail to create the correct xpath. This is the exact sequence with the tags within I should get the text, but this is an email msg, so I can’t provide url.